# Iterating over JArray in NLua

Tags: c#, lua, json.net, nlua

I'm trying to iterate over a `JArray` in NLua, but can't somehow.
JArray's are treaten as userdata (what is userdata?) and thus can't be iterated over.

Converting the `JArray` to an `JValue[]` with a c# method doesn't work either.

There are two possible solutions as far as I can see.
1. Getting a working Iterable function for nlua.
2. Converting the JArray to a Lua Table and then use a for loop on top of it.

I have not succeeded at any of those two.
Is there anyone with more experience on this?
Thank you in advance.

things I tried:

regCommands is a JArray containing a lot of JObjects in JTokens

```
    jArray = Json:parseJArray(regCommands)

    for k, v in ipairs(jArray) do

        print(k.. " ".. v)

    end
```

this gives the error on ipairs(jArray) that jArray is userdata.

```
    Json:parseJArray(JArray)
```

is a c# function wich takes a JArray and spits out a JToken[]

something else I tried:

```
    keyVal = regCommands.First
    while keyVal ~= nil do
        if (type(JProperty)) then
            regCommands[keyVal.Name:lower()] = keyVal.First
        end
        keyVal = keyVal.Next
    end
```

this crashes at
`regCommands[keyVal.Name:lower()] = keyVal.first`
whitout any logical reasons.

even getting a c# enumerator doesn't work

```
    enumCommands = regCommands:GetEnumerator()

    enumCommands:MoveNext()
    repeat

        enumCommands:MoveNext()
    until enumCommands:Current() ~= nil
```

Comment: Have you try anything then some in your Question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To iterate over a .NET collection you can use luanet.each function, which will return the function to iterate through .NET enumerables objects.

```
local each = luanet.each

for k in each(jArray) do
    print (k)
end
```

Exemple: https://github.com/codefoco/NLuaBox/blob/00af36aa480281ae33835173430a806c54c2f9dc/Resources/source/ScriptsDataSource.lua#L166

Comment: that sounds promising, I'll try it tomorrow

Comment: Good ;) if works, remember to mark my answer as "selected answer". Thank you.